# Using multiple views in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view

Is it possible to select from multiple views in a stored procedure? I've tried, but to no avail. bI feel as though it is because my implementation is wrong. Here's my code if anyone wants to take a look. When I add this sp to the linq designer and it generates a result class it only has the fields selected from the savedarticle_v view, and not tag_v.

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mobile_GetSavedArticlesAR] 
  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @UserID int , 

  @keyword1 varchar(50)='',
  @keyword2 varchar(50)='',
  @keyword3 varchar(50)='',
  @keyword4 varchar(50)='',
  @keyword5 varchar(50)='',
  @Page int=1,
  @PageLen int=20

AS
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
  declare @RowStart int
  declare @RowEnd int
  IF (@Page=1)
    Begin

      set @RowStart=(@Page-1)*(@PageLen)
      set @RowEnd=(@RowStart+@PageLen);
    END
  ELSE
    BEGIN

      set @RowStart=((@Page-1)*(@PageLen))+1
      set @RowEnd=((@RowStart+@PageLen))-1
    END;
    With myArticles as 
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY userID DESC) as 'RowNumber',*

From savedarticle_v
where UserID=@UserID and
title like '%'+@keyword1+'%' and
title like '%'+@keyword2+'%' and
title like '%'+@keyword3+'%' and
title like '%'+@keyword4+'%' and
title like '%'+@keyword5+'%' 
)


    select 
      rownumber,journalID,journalname,articleID,title,publicationdate,likes,aviews,comments ,medabbr
      from  myArticles where RowNumber Between @RowStart  and @RowEnd;

With myTags as
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY userID DESC) as 'RowNumber',*

From tags_v
where userID=@UserID
)
    select tagtext from myTags where RowNumber Between @RowStart and @RowEnd
END



GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with views, but everything with the fact that you have a multiple resultset stored procedure.

An approach to process multiple resultsets from Linq-to-Sql is described in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/02/04/linq-to-sql-returning-multiple-result-sets.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ designer does not natively support multiple rowsets.

The trusty method of reading multiple result sets is the regular ADO.NET `SqlDataReader` with its `NextResult` method.

A better ORM than LINQ is [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).  It supports multiple result sets with the `QueryMultiple` method.